# SSIS data conversion (from unicode to ANSI) returned status value 4

Tags: ssis, data-conversion, ansi, non-unicode

I have the following problem:

I have an SSIS package that starts with a query executed at an Oracle DB and I would like to export a Fixed Width flat file with ANSI 1253 Code Page. I get an error:

> The data conversion for column [column_name] returned status value 4
>   and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no
>   match in the target code page"

The problem has to do with the second part of the message, as the width is ok. I tried to use Data Conversion from Toolbox but it didn't work (probably I didn't use it on the right way). I have only `select` privileges to the database so I cannot add any sql procedures to remove special characters at the query. Also the idea to load data to a staging table wouldn't be the best choice at my case. Does anyone has any idea on how to convert my data without getting this error?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Load data using your Source from Oracle DB and keep the data types they are giving you.

add a derived column and cast your column.

```
(DT_STR,[Insert Length],1252) [columnName]
```

if the column is ntext you need to do 2 steps to get to string.

```
(DT_STR...) (DT_WSTR) Ntextcolumn
```